# MsgPack for compressing json data, why not using gzip/deflate?

Tags: compression, gzip, deflate, msgpack

I heard something about [MsgPack](http://msgpack.org/) that can be used for compressing json messages, but I have a question about that, why not simply using Gzip/Deflate instead of MsgPack? I think it's so better to debugging also.

Comment: There's no real difference in size between JSON and MsgPack after gzip. ([benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/maxpert/3116560))

Comment: Another test that gives some thought about it https://www.peterbe.com/plog/msgpack-vs-json-with-gzip

Answer (score 34, accepted):

msgpack is an *efficient binary serialization format* that you may want to choose as an alternative to JSON according to your use case.

Even if it is advertised as *like JSON, but fast and small*, it is **not** intended to *compress JSON data*. Once again think of it as an alternative, and keep in mind that as stated by its author:

> there are many situations where it simply does not offer enough advantage to JSON

I would greatly recommend you to read this article - [My thoughts on MessagePack](https://gist.github.com/2908191), written by msgpack's author, that includes everything you need to know vs. recommended msgpack use cases, pros/cons and other useful pointers related to msgpack and JSON.